# DateListLogPlot Axis Labels

Tags: plotting, labeling, date-and-time

**I have the following code:**

```
names = CountryData[];
data = CountryData[#, {"Population", {1920,2010}}] &/@ names;
cleaned = DeleteMissing[data/.{}->Nothing];
sum = TimeSeriesThread[Total, cleaned];
DateListLogPlot[sum, AxesLabel->{"Time (Years)", "Log(Population)"}]
```

This gives the estimated world population increase as a function of time on a Log plot.

I would like to be able to explicitly label my axes, but this doesn't seem to work with `DateListPlot` or `DateListLogPlot`. `AxesLabel` doesn't throw an error when passed to either of these functions, but it also doesn't result in the desired output.

Checking over the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) for `DateListPlot`, `AxesLabel` doesn't appear as an option, and none of the example plots have y-axis labels.

*Am I missing something obvious, or is there really no way to title/label the y-axis in `DateListPlot` or `DateListLogPlot`?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
names = CountryData[];
data = CountryData[#, {"Population", {1920, 2010}}] & /@ names;
cleaned = DeleteMissing[data /. {} -> Nothing];
sum = TimeSeriesThread[Total, cleaned];

DateListLogPlot[sum,
 FrameLabel -> {{"one", "two"}, {"three", "four"}},
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold, 16],
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

You can search for more options for `Frame` on the `Plot` page, if need be. I hope it helps you.

[image]

Comment: `FrameLabel -> {{"one", None}, {"three", None}}` in case you want to skip labels.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't aware of the `Frame` or `FrameLabel` options. It seems like `DateListPlot` Automatically adds `Frame->True`, but even if you pass `Frame->False` along with an `AxesLabel` argument, it doesn't label the axes.

Your solution works great though!

Comment: The documentation on these commands needs an update to include `Frame` related options. You asked if you were "missing something obvious". Obviously not.